# Inserting a CDATA section into XML generated by a Restlet web service using SAX

Tags: xml, restlet, cdata

I need to embed some HTML in some of my XML nodes and the consumer wants it inside a CDATA section.  They want the CDATA to be preserved as `<![CDATA[ ]]>.`  But the opening and closing angle brackets are being escaped so they are receiving this instead `&lt;![CDATA[]]&gt;`.  I have tried a number of different methods but nothing seems to work.  And there doesn't appear to be any functionality built into the Restlet framework.  Has anyone else faced this issue and found a solution?  Here's a sample of my code:

```
@Get
public Representation toXml() {

    // Create a new SAX representation
    SaxRepresentation result = new SaxRepresentation() {

        public void write(org.restlet.ext.xml.XmlWriter writer)
                throws IOException {
...

        try {
                // Start document
                writer.startDocument();

                // Append the root node
                writer.startElement(COMPANIES); 

      // I want to start the CDATA section here.

      writer.startElement(BRANCHES);
                if((mfgRepList != null) && (mfgRepList.size() > 0)){
                    writer = MfgRep.getMfgRepHtml(writer, mfgRepList);  
                }
                writer.endElement(BRANCHES);

      // I want to end the CDATA section here.


      writer.endElement(COMPANIES);

      writer.endDocument();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
                throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }; // end of write

    }; // end of create new Sax representation

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the restlet code, it looks like they "escape" all strings/characters.  So, in this case, I believe the only solution is to "write" around the xml writer through the output stream:

```
    writer.getWriter().write("<![CDATA[");
    // insert CDATA data here
    writer.getWriter().write("]]");
```

There may be other solutions, but this seemed the most straight forward in this case.  I believe
it is an oversight in the restlet api.

Comment: Bravo, Grady!  That did the trick.  I really appreciate your efforts. Stackoverflow comes through once again.  This has to be one of the greatest brain trusts on the planet.